# What is cohort effect in general?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, panel-data, biostatistics, case-cohort

I have run into cohort effect in longitudinal data analysis book for quite a while. However, I still could not quite grasp what is cohort effect.

What is the meaning of cohort effect and how it will impact longitudinal data analysis f ignored? My superficial guess is that the population will have some time-varying covariates which are used to represent cohort effect. Is every such time-varying covariate cohort effect?